# Copy nested list and fill it with consecutive numbers

Tags: python

Given this nested list:

```
foo = [["apple", "cherry"], ["banana"], ["pear", "raspberry", "pineapple"]]
```

I want to keep the structure and replace all items by consecutive numbers. My desired output is:

```
[[0, 1], [2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

I was hoping for a simple one-liner, but the shortest working solution I came up with was:

```
foo_numbers = []
count = 0

for i, sublist in enumerate(foo):
    foo_numbers.append([])
    for item in sublist:
        foo_numbers[i].append(count)
        count += 1
```

Usually these manual iterators indicate that there is a more pythonic way to achieve the same thing. If this is to be done with list comprehension, I couldn't see how to make up a "shared counter" for both loops, so it wouldn't start from zero for every `sublist`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) with a nested list comprehension:

```
from itertools import count

foo = [["apple", "cherry"], ["banana"], ["pear", "raspberry", "pineapple"]]

c = count()  # 0 start is default, e.g. count(1) will start from 1
res = [[next(c) for _ in lst] for lst in foo]

print(res)
# [[0, 1], [2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: That's neat! By default I don't import itertools and I usually prefer plain python, but it's definitely better than my bulky solution

Comment: Just note: using `timeit`seems to indicate that this solution is slower than your original code

Answer (score 2):

Comparing these solutions:

```
import itertools

def f1(foo):
    """original version in question"""
    foo_numbers = []
    count = 0
    for i, sublist in enumerate(foo):
        foo_numbers.append([])
        for item in sublist:
            foo_numbers[i].append(count)
            count += 1
    return foo_numbers

def f2(foo):
    """@jpp answer"""
    c = itertools.count()
    return [[next(c) for _ in range(len(lst))] for lst in foo]

def f3(foo):
    """@DanielMesejo answer"""
    foo_numbers = []
    count = 0
    for i, sublist in enumerate(foo):
        foo_numbers.append([j for j in range(count, len(sublist) + count)])
        count += len(sublist)
    return foo_numbers
```

Gives us this:

```
>>> import timeit
>>>
>>> timeit.timeit('f(foo)', 'from __main__ import f1 as f, foo')
1.2990377170499414
>>> timeit.timeit('f(foo)', 'from __main__ import f2 as f, foo')
2.260929798008874
>>> timeit.timeit('f(foo)', 'from __main__ import f3 as f, foo')
2.1552230638917536
```

It seems the original version is faster (by a factor of 2).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! In fact time is not the issue. My list isn't really that much bigger than the example code and it's only called once. But these for-loops leave me puzzled when I come back to the code a year later and wonder what they do. So I was looking for something slim

Comment: How come two nested `for loop`s are quicker than `list comprehension`?

Comment: @offeltoffel I don't know either, why for loops are faster than list comprehension in this case. I just made the timing tests and was surprised myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), instead of the inner loop:

```
foo = [["apple", "cherry"], ["banana"], ["pear", "raspberry", "pineapple"]]

foo_numbers = []
count = 0

for i, sublist in enumerate(foo):
    foo_numbers.append([j for j in range(count, len(sublist) + count)])
    count += len(sublist)

print(foo_numbers)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1], [2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

In general list comprehensions are faster than loops for list creation. As an alternative you could convert the range object to a list, like this:

```
foo_numbers.append(list(range(count, len(sublist) + count)))
```

Comment: `range(count, len(sublist) + count)` was kind of a missing puzzle piece missing to make up this solution on my own. Thanks for clearing my vision there

Comment: Just a note: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54328251/9225671); it seems that this version is also slower as the original code

Answer (score 0):

Use below given solution if you really [**do not**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54328027/copy-nested-list-and-fill-it-with-consecutive-numbers/54328487#comment95474209_54328079) want to import anything:

```
foo = [["apple", "cherry"], ["banana"], ["pear", "raspberry", "pineapple"]]

count = -1

def indexer(fruits):
    global count
    count += 1
    return count


foo_new = list(map(lambda fruits: list(map(indexer, fruits)), foo))

print(foo_new)
```

#### Outputs:

```
[[0, 1], [2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: This answer has some nice ideas in it. I am not really restricted, it is more some personal preference. Thanks!